# What is the biblical basis for a pretribulation rapture?

Tags: biblical-basis, eschatology, rapture, premillennialism, tribulation

I am looking not for deductions, or interpretations that some preacher insists upon. I need a scripture which is irrefutable. Can anyone give me one?

Comment: Irrefutable? If that was the case no one would dispute it!

Comment: Hello, E Hall, have you availed yourself of the search feature of this site?  You can use the search term "rapture" or "tribulation" (I'd recommend the former) and get a list of already asked and answered questions regarding the rapture.   You may not only find what you ask about, but a great deal more.